# What exactly is a set?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, philosophy

It's been proven that the Continuum Hypothesis is independent of ZFC, yet some people still talk about it being "true" or "false", or that we need to search for a non-mathematical justification for it. But I'm not really sure what all of this means.

The way I see it, the fact that CH is independent just means that there's two versions of the concept of sets, but both are equally valid, similar to the way the independence of the parallels postulate means that there are two versions of geometry (Euclidean and Hyperbolic).

But if I think about the natural numbers, and take some statement $P$ independent of Peano Arithmetic, I wouldn't say "there's two versions of the natural numbers, both of which are equally valid", because I have some "physical model" of the natural numbers (by drawing dots on a sheet of paper, for example). I would say that it's possible to justify either $P$ or $\lnot P$, and that if we assumed the other one, it wouldn't be right to call the objects we're talking about "natural numbers".

So my question is, when people talk about something like the CH being true/false, do they have some "intuitive model" of what a set is, and if yes, what does it look like?

Comment: You can draw infinitely many dots on a paper? That's impressive!

Comment: Are you familiar with Platonism vs. Formalism? Many mathematicians are platonists (Goedel was one).

Comment: generally in science, and this includes mathematics, there is no answer to questions as "what is X?" where X is a concept, because sciences are essentially descriptive. Or in other words: a thing is defined by it properties. In this sense a set is defined by the set theoretic model where it is defined.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin More or less. I guess my question is what do Platonists consider "set" to mean? Everyone agrees that there's a single version of "natural numbers", and everyone agrees there's different versions of "geometry". So do the Platonists who talk about CH being true/false agree on a precise, unambiguous, idea of what "set" means, similar to the way we do for natural numbers?

Comment: When you say "some people talk about CH being true or false", it would be really helpful to give some references. MSE doesnt work well for people who are asking for opinions on hearsay evidence.

Comment: Here's an example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14338/what-is-the-general-opinion-on-the-generalized-continuum-hypothesis

Comment: @RobArthan The existence of Platonist mathematicians is I believe common knowledge - I don't think that claim requires a citation at all.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: my point is not about the existence of Platonist mathematicians but about the details of the maths that the OP wants help with.  The last paragraph of the OP's question is essentially about psychology, not mathematics.

Comment: Stefan, not everyone agree on a single version of the natural numbers. If I think that inaccessible cardinals are consistent, and you think they are not, then we are fundamentally in disagreement about the natural numbers.

Comment: But at least, does everyone agree that there's only one "correct" model of what we should call natural numbers, even though we might not agree on which one it is? My question is why some people think there is a "correct" model of sets, rather than saying that there are many different models of set theory, the same way there are many different models of, for example, the group axioms or the topological space axioms.

Comment: Wolfram *MathWorld* is always a great place to start. Read through Stover’s and Weisstein’s [article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Set.html) and tell me if you still have any questions.

Comment: From the formalist perspective, you talk about theorems as a consequence of ZF(C) or whatever you choose, since the precise statement in logic is ultimately ZFC => _, which is just "true", independent of whether you accept a model of ZFC as having any relevance to the real world.